# How to access Angular Application through Kubernetes Ingress file

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have angular application which is currently running in pod in kubernetes cluster, I am able to access the application through Pod ip followed by port, but not able to access through my ingress url.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.10.0 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
ARG configuration=production
RUN npm run build -- --output-path=./dist/out --configuration $configuration

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
#Copy ci-dashboard-dist
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
#Copy default nginx configuration
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Ingress file

```
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
  kind: "Ingress"
  metadata: 
    name: "angular-app"
    namespace: "development"
    annotations: 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
      
  spec: 
    rules: 
      - 
        host: "localhost"
        http: 
          paths: 
            - 
              backend: 
                serviceName: "angular-ser"
                servicePort: 80
              path: "/angular-app/ser/(.*)"
```

When I am trying to access the application through Pod ip it is working fine, but when I am trying to access it through ingress path, it is loading the nginx home page.

I tried every possible combination but the page is appearing to be blank when I am trying to access with Ingress path url.

Also I did inspect on the page and there in console section found these errors.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)
runtime-es2015.362517ed12c07fa8e977.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)
polyfills-es2015.9147b0c83e6774bdcaea.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)
main-es2015.2f24ff2a3689aa55a7aa.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)
scripts.28bddca5d494a37163be.js:1

Comment: 1. Is your angular app deployment deployed in the development namespace? As the Ingress rules must reside in the namespace where the app that they configure reside. 2. Could you also add an output from the `curl -v host/path` command (for both, your pod ip and ingress path), so we could see that's the difference? 3. Could you try to delete the `rewrite-target` and try with your app default path? Does it work then correctly?

Comment: 1. Yes, angular app deployed in development namespace. 2. Not sure how to do it, can you please share more information on it. 3. Yes, I did tried by removing rewrite-target, but it is only giving an empty page, but when I am trying to access with pod ip it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are having `host` as an empty string and it should have a value.

try having `localhost` or just remove the `host` part totally so you can access it by localhost by default.

Then open the browser and write `http://localhost/angular-app/ser/...`

Comment: Hi, Sorry forgot to mention I have given the host name just keeping it as private